# print swt component even if hidden by scrollbar

Tags: java, printing, swt, components, visible

I try to print a  swt TreeViewer to png file. With:

```
Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();
Image image = new Image(display, tree.getSize().x, tree.getParent().getSize().y);
GC gc = new GC(image);

System.out.println(new File(pathToSave).getAbsolutePath());
tree.print(gc);

ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
loader.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
loader.save(pathToSave, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
gc.dispose();
image.dispose();
```

the png contains only the visible part of the tree. The tree has a scrollbar because it contains more elements than fit on the form.

I would like to print the tree with all elements visible and without scrollbar. Any ideas?

On swing components i could use .paintall().. swt components don't seem to know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the size of the image should have the size the tree would have without scrolls, and not the current size. For that you should use `computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true)`. Then you should resize the tree that size, print, and then resize it back. Since you don't want users to notice that, during this operation you should disabled draws with `setRedraw(false)`.

Here is a full snippet that does all this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Tree tree = new Tree(composite, SWT.NONE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        final TreeItem treeItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
        treeItem.setText(String.format("item %d long                      name", i));
    }
    tree.addListener(SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            tree.getParent().setRedraw(false);
            final Point originalSize = tree.getSize();
            final Point size = tree.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);
            final Image image = new Image(display, size.x, size.y);
            final GC gc = new GC(image);

            tree.setSize(size);
            tree.print(gc);
            tree.setSize(originalSize);

            final ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
            loader.data = new ImageData[]{image.getImageData()};
            final String pathToSave = "out.png";
            System.out.println(new File(pathToSave).getAbsolutePath());
            loader.save(pathToSave, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
            gc.dispose();
            image.dispose();
            tree.getParent().setRedraw(true);
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Press enter to save the file.

Comment: Does that work if the `Tree` is to big to even fit on the screen (after resizing it)?

Comment: that is exactly what i was searching for. I never thought about disabling redraw. thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @Baz I tested with 1000 items, and my monitor is big, but not that big :)

Comment: @Baz yes, my tree is 400 x 68000 and is printed nicely

Comment: @andi Excellent. +1 in this case :)